# Function that sorts an array of structures alphabetically by one of their string values

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

For one of my assignments I am required to write a code that takes input from a text file that has a number of TA's available at the top line and each line afterwards containing values for Name, Day, start hour, and end hour.

Right now I have the function that reads the file and the function that prints the output working the way I need them but however whenever I include the sort function that I wrote the program will crash.

What I did with the sort function I used strcmp() inside of nested forloops in order to cycle through the array and determine which values supersede the other in alphabetical order. Then I used strcpy() in along with a temp structure to store a value, swap one value with the other, and then swap the other value with the stored value in the temp structure.

I think the probelm might have something to do with the way I used strcpy() with structures since I think the way it works is I'm call the address and not the actual value and I might need to use pointers but I'm not entirely sure. Here's the function that's giving me trouble:

```
void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[],int num_shifts)
{

int x,y;


for(x = 0 ; x < num_shifts  ; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < num_shifts ; y++)
    {
        if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
            strcpy(temp.name, shift_data[x].name);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].name, shift_data[x].name);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].name, temp.name);

        }
        if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
             strcpy(temp.day_of_week, shift_data[x].day_of_week);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].day_of_week, shift_data[x].day_of_week);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].day_of_week, temp.day_of_week);
        }
       if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
            strcpy(temp.start_hour, shift_data[x].start_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].start_hour, shift_data[x].start_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].start_hour, temp.start_hour);
        }
     if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
             strcpy(temp.end_hour, shift_data[x].end_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[x].end_hour, shift_data[y].end_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].end_hour, temp.end_hour);
        }

}

}
}
```

And here's the complete code:

```
// Henry Moench
// 12/2/15
// COP3223C-15FALL 0002
// Homework 7

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//initializing structures
struct Shift
     {
        char name[100];
        char day_of_week[100];
        int start_hour;
        int end_hour;
     };

struct Shift shift_data[100];
struct Shift temp;

int main()
{
//initializing variable and calling functions
int num_shifts;

     num_shifts= read_data(shift_data);

     sort_data(shift_data, num_shifts);

     print_data(shift_data, num_shifts);

    return 0;
}


//creating function that reads the text file indicated by the user
//and then storing the data into a structure array
int read_data(struct Shift shift_data[])
     {

     char input[100];
     int x;
     int num_shifts;
     printf("What is the name of the file? ");
        scanf("%s", &input);
        FILE *ifp;
        ifp = fopen(input, "r");
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num_shifts);

for(x = 0 ; x < num_shifts; x++)
        {

            fscanf(ifp, "%s", &shift_data[x].name);
            fscanf(ifp, "%s", &shift_data[x].day_of_week);
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &shift_data[x].start_hour);
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &shift_data[x].end_hour);
        }
        fclose(ifp);
        return num_shifts;
     }

//creates function that prints out the output in the format specified
void print_data(struct Shift shift[], int num_shifts)
    {
   int x;
   printf("TA Shifts \n");
   printf("================================================ \n");

   for(x = 0; x < num_shifts; x++)
   {
   printf(" %s",shift_data[x].name);
   printf(" %s",shift_data[x].day_of_week);


   if(shift_data[x].start_hour>12)
   {
       shift_data[x].start_hour=shift_data[x].start_hour-12;
       printf("%2d:00 pm to  ", shift_data[x].start_hour);
   }
   else if(shift_data[x].start_hour<12)
   {
       printf("%2d:00 am to  ", shift_data[x].start_hour);
   }
   else if(shift_data[x].start_hour==12)
   {
       printf("%2d:00 pm to  ", shift_data[x].start_hour);
   }


   if(shift_data[x].end_hour>12)
   {
       shift_data[x].end_hour=shift_data[x].end_hour-12;
       printf("%2d:00 pm\n", shift_data[x].end_hour);
   }
   else if(shift_data[x].end_hour<12)
   {
       printf("%2d:00 am\n", shift_data[x].end_hour);
   }
   else if(shift_data[x].end_hour==12)
   {
       printf("%2d:00 pm\n", shift_data[x].end_hour);
   }

   }
    }


void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[],int num_shifts)
{

int x,y;


for(x = 0 ; x < num_shifts  ; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < num_shifts ; y++)
    {
        if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
            strcpy(temp.name, shift_data[x].name);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].name, shift_data[x].name);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].name, temp.name);

        }
        if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
             strcpy(temp.day_of_week, shift_data[x].day_of_week);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].day_of_week, shift_data[x].day_of_week);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].day_of_week, temp.day_of_week);
        }
       if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
            strcpy(temp.start_hour, shift_data[x].start_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].start_hour, shift_data[x].start_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].start_hour, temp.start_hour);
        }
     if(strcmp(shift_data[x].name,shift_data[y].name)<0)
        {
             strcpy(temp.end_hour, shift_data[x].end_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[x].end_hour, shift_data[y].end_hour);
            strcpy(shift_data[y].end_hour, temp.end_hour);
        }

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash may happen because you are trying to use strcpy() on an int field, which it will not work on ( read the description of the strcpy() function to work out why ).

I would suggest you manage the data differently while sorting.

Instead of sorting an array of structs, keep the array to work on as an array of index values.

So you have your original read in data in the same array you have now.

But you sort an array with just index values to that array.

```
int tmp[sizeof(shift_data)] ;

int i = 0 ;

for( i = 0 ; i < sizeof(tmp) ; i++ )
    tmp[i] = i ;
```

Now when you want to swap elements k and j of the array you just do :

```
int m ;

m = tmp[j] ;
tmp[j] = tmp[k] ;
tmp[k] = m ;
```

And that is *much* quicker than your strcpy() stuff.

To compare to names do

```
int res ;

res = strcmp( shift_data[ tmp[j] ].name, shift_data[ tmp[k] ].name ) ;
```

And note that in your code you do the equivalent of the following :

```
if ( A.n < B.n )
    swap( A.n, B.n ) ;

if ( A.n < B.n )
    swap( A.x, B.x ) ;
```

but if you needed to swap because A.n < B.n to start with, then the second comparison will give a different result to the first, as you swapped the n fields.  This would mix up your data.

You should have had all the swap operations wrapped inside a single if() statement.  If you use the index array method I describe you will not need to do all that anyway, just the comparison.

When you have sorted your final array you can print it in order using

```
int i = 0 ;

for( i = 0 ; i < sizeof(tmp) ; i++ )
{
    printf( "name is %s\n", shift_data[ tmp[i] ].name ) ;
}
```

You can move the shift_data elements around after the sort if you want.

Finally you should look at different sorting algorithms.